# How to train svm model in python with scikit and use it for predictions in C++?

Tags: python, c++, scikit-learn, svm, libsvm

I would like to know, if there is the possibility to somehow train a svm classifier using scikit in python (love this module and its documentation) and import that trained model into C++ for prediction making.

Here is how far I got:

- I have written a python script which uses scikit to create a reasonable svm classifier
- I can also store that model in pickle format

Now, I had a look at libSVM for C++ but I do not see how that is able to import such a model. I think that the documentation is not that good or I missed something here.

However, I also thought that instead of storing the whole model, I could just store the parameters of the SVM Classifier and load only those parameters ( I think the needed once are: Support Vectors, C, degree) for a linear SVM classifier. Unfortunately, I cannot find any documentation of libSVM on how to do that.

A last option which I would not prefer that much would be to go with OpenCV in which I could train a SVM classifier, store it and load it back all in C++. But this would introduce even more library dependencies (especially such a large one) for my program. If there is a good way to avoid that, I would love to do so.

As always I thank you in advance!

Best,
Tukk